# How to render DOM using props in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

Implement and `export` a new React Component **`TableHeader`** that will represent the heading row for *any* table. This class should expect a `prop` called **`cols`** that is an *array* of column names (as Strings). The class should render a `<thead>` (table head) element containing a `<tr>` (table row). Inside the `<tr>` should be a set of `<th>` (table heading) elements, one for each String in the `cols` prop.

Use the `.map()` function to convert the `cols` prop into an array of `<th>` DOM elements (using JSX and *inline expressions*), and then include this array in the returned DOM elements.

Be sure to give each `<th>` element a `key` attribute (the column name string is a fine value) so that React can keep track of it.

Include an instance of the `TableHeader` class in DOM rendered by the `SenatorTable` class (as a child of the `<table>`). The `SenatorTable` class should pass the `TableHeader` it creates a `cols` prop that is the array `['Name', 'State', 'Phone', 'Twitter']`.

This should cause the heading row to appear in the table (with the correct 4 columns).

This what I've already tried, however; I do not understand how I work with the props and make it properly render.

```
export class TableHeader extends Component {
  render() {
    let colItems = this.props.cols.map((colName) => {
      return <th message={colName} key={colName}/>;
    });

    return (
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {colItems}
        </tr>
      </thead>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: this code should work as long as you invoke `Tableheader` with right props.

Comment: You don't need to cut and paste your entire assignment text, just the part you're stuck on. You don't say what actually happens. Seems fine at first glance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `th` tag doesn't have a message attribute.

You need to wrap the column name in an opening and closing `th` tag

```
 let colItems = this.props.cols.map((colName) => {
      return <th key={colName}>{colName}</th>;
    });
```